# не работает @media на одном классе css

Tags: html, css, css3, media-queries

есть такой код
html

```
<div class="triangle">
 <div class="arrow1 down">
</div><div class="arrow2 down">
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.arrow1 {
        /* border: solid #0059f6; */
    border-width: 0 8px 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 12px 8px 0px rgba(0, 89, 246, 0.96);
    -moz-box-shadow: 15px 15px 8px 0px rgba(0, 89, 246, 0.96);
    box-shadow: 18px 17px 8px 0px rgba(0, 89, 246, 0.96);
    position: absolute;
    /* margin-bottom: -267px; */
    margin-top: -21px;
}
.arrow2{
    /*border: solid #0059f6;*/
    border-width: 0 8px 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
     -webkit-box-shadow:-12px -12px 8px 0px rgba(0, 89, 246, 0.96) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: -15px -15px 8px 0px rgba(0, 89, 246, 0.96) inset;
box-shadow: -15px -15px 8px 0px rgba(0, 89, 246, 0.96) inset;
}
.down {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
} 
  .triangle{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 515px;
  }
```

хочу сделать media запрос

```
@media(max-width:765px){
  .triangle{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 465px;
  }
}
```

но почему то он не работает, класс triangle не меняется, хотя такой же запрос для других классов исправно работает, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Смотрите, что в отладчике происходит. Скорее всего ваше правило с `@media` находится раньше основных правил и они его перетирают

Comment: @media находится в самом конце, и не должно ничего перетирать

Comment: Проверил ваш код - [всё работает](https://codepen.io/lugan0/pen/VwPWKwQ) (добавил фон для наглядности при переключении)

Comment: Очень странно, у меня по какой-то причине ничего не меняется, все остальные классы меняются кроме .triangle

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось неожиданным, в медиа запросе я поменял max-width на max-device-width, и все заработало